# Bash get return value of a command and exit with this value

Tags: bash

I want to execute a command then get the return value of this command.
when  it's done i want to exit and give exit the return value of the previous command, the one i just executed. I already have this piece of code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
exec gosu user /var/www/bin/phpunit -c app
typeset ret_code
ret_code=$?
if [ $ret_code == 0 ]; then
    exit 0
fi

exit 1
```

how can i do it ? thanks

Comment: why not just `return $?` or `return $ret_code` immediately after `exec...`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `$?` will *always* be non-zero if you reach code following `exec`. `exec` only returns if it fails.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think your problem is that `typeset` itself creates a return value of 0. Try

```
gosu user /var/www/bin/phpunit -c app
ret_code=$?
return $ret_code
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `exec` only returns if it fails, so you'll never see a zero exit status.

```
exec gosu user /var/www/bin/phpunit -c app
ret_code=$?
printf 'Error in execing gosu, %d\n' $ret_code
exit $ret_code
```

Note this error has nothing to do with `gosu`; if `exec` returns, it is because the shell was unable to even *start* `gosu`, not because `gosu` itself exited with an error.

Perhaps you didn't mean to use `exec`, and simply want to run the command and wait for it to complete?

```
gosu user /var/www/bin/phpunit -c app
ret_code=$?
if [ $ret_code = 0 ]; then exit 0; fi
printf 'Error in execing gosu, %d\n' $ret_code
exit $ret_code
```

Answer (score 5):

Know it has been awhile, but here is more a one liner.

Something like this...

```
if [ $(gosu user /var/www/bin/phpunit -c app;echo $?) ]; then
    exit 0
fi

exit 1
```

Or even shorter...

```
return $(gosu user /var/www/bin/phpunit -c app;echo $?)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to check if two strings are the same on the command line it's easier to use the `test` command

```
[ 'abc' = '123' ]; echo $?
```

prints `0` if strings are the same, `1` otherwise.
Don't forget to use spaces inside the `[]`