# $status command not returning anything in terminal despite "command not found" being thrown by the previously launched program

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, status

The title pretty much says it all.

I'm launching a program, passing it the parameter "fail" as a way to make it fail, since that program needs the name of a real runnable program as a parameter, and the shell throws a `sh: 1: fail: not found` as a result.

I'm trying to obtain the return value of the command with the variable `$status` ( I need to use this variable as a test) and I'm not getting any return value, while the return should be 127 for such case.

Might seem like a pretty trivial situation but I would appreciate it somebody could come up with an explanation for this.

My program is a C program which returns the return value of a `system` which use the program passed as a parameter.

Comment: `with the variable $status` Why $status? Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801947/bash-get-return-value-of-a-command-and-exit-with-this-value/43802810  ?

Comment: This comes from a shell script that checks if $status is equal to a specific value and I'm obligated to use this script for my test.

Comment: `$status` is not a standard variable and has no meaning outside of whatever you have chosen to use it for